# Listener configuration

Tags: apache-kafka

I m trying to understand how listener configuration work in Kafka. I installed Apache Kafka on my local machine, and I have this configuration initially and commented out advertised listeners part:

```
listeners = PLAINTEXT://localhost:9092
```

and when I run Kafka cli to list topics, It works fine. However, when I add advertised listeners something like below, the cli's to describe/list doesn't work with the localhost

```
listeners = PLAINTEXT://localhost:9092
advertised.listeners=PLAINTEXT://hostname.local:9092
listener.security.protocol.map=PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT,INTERNAL:PLAINTEXT,EXTERNAL:PLAINTEXT
```

and here is how I m trying to list the topics:

```
 bin/kafka-topics.sh --list --bootstrap-server localhost:9092
```

Answer (score 0):

`listeners` is the address used by the embedded server in kafka to bind to. `localhost:9092` will only accept local connections. A listener of `0.0.0.0:9092` will accept all external-host connections on that port. This server is used to provide TCP protocol that provides the control plane for Kafka clients.

`advertised.listeners` is used by Zookeeper or Raft to return addresses of Kafka brokers to Kafka clients. When `advertised.listeners` is not set, the value of `listeners` is used here.

You should try,

`bin/kafka-topics.sh --list --bootstrap-server hostname.local:9092`